# List project number, project name and number of employees for all projects > 2 employees working on it

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

There are two relevant tables: works_on and project. Project contains the following attributes: PName, PNo, PLocation and DNo (department number). Works_on contains the following attributes: SSN, PNo, hours.

I want to only count the SSNs that appear more than twice and then provide the count value, PName and PNo.

This is my attempt so far:

```
SELECT
    P.PNo, P.PName, 
    COUNT(W.SSN) AS no_employees
FROM
    project AS P INNER JOIN works_on AS W ON P.PNO = W.PNo
WHERE W.SSN IN (SELECT SSN FROM WORKS_ON GROUP BY SSN HAVING COUNT(SSN) > 2)
GROUP BY P.PNo
```

but I get the wrong PNo's and the wrong number of employees. I have been trying to figure out why this code will not give me projects with more than two employees. Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need inner query, `group by` with `having` should do, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.no, p.name, COUNT(w.ssn) as employees
FROM project p JOIN works_on w ON p.pno = w.pno
GROUP BY p.no, p.name
HAVING employees > 2;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Still not sure why we're doing your homework. Was that part of the assignment?

Comment: I've been at this for a few hours so I think by reaching out here I am not asking you to do my homework, but instead asking for insight or help. I am new to SQL and am trying to learn from my mistakes. I'm really not sure why you're wasting both of our time without offering any help.